# rotation matrix to facing direction vector

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I have a position of a character as xyz coordinates x= 102, y= 0.75, z= -105.7 for example. And i have the rotation matrix for the character as

```
M11 = -0.14
M12 = 0
M13 = -0.99
M21 = 0
M22 = 1
M23 = 0
M31 = 0.99
M32 =0
M33 = 0.14
```

I don't have much understanding about graphics and how these data can correlate to the facing direction of the character. I want to find a vector such that i can use that vector to aim at a direction that the character is facing. How do i do that?

Comment: Where are you getting those matrices from?

Comment: Is this about [tag:unity3d], [tag:xna] or general [tag:math]? Because at least XNA provides a simple property for getting the facing direction.

Comment: i'm using xna. The matrix values and the position are from the memory of a game. The position is accurate and tested. not sure about the matrix values though...I construct a matrix using the 9 values above, then get a vector from matrix.forward method. but it doesn't give me the facing direction properly because if i shoot something (fire an animation) in this direction, it is not the direction the character is facing.

Comment: Note.  *if you were* using Unity3D, you use the "LookAt" command. The whole, entire, point of a game engine is that you never ever use matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction your character is facing is the 3rd row of the rotation matrix. So that would be:

```
Vector3 facingDirection = new Vector3(0.99f, 0f, 0.14f);//(m31,m32,m33)
```

this vector appears to be normalized, but if it weren't, you would do:

```
Vector3 facingDirection = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0.99f, 0f, 0.14f));
```

If the matrix is an XNA Matrix, then you would simply use the `Matrix.Forward` property of the Matrix structure and get the same result.

Comment: Hi Steve, i'm already doing what you are suggesting, but the problem is i want to fire at this direction from the position of the character. Lets say i have a command fire x=1, y=2, z=3 to fire at position (1,2,3) from the character's current position. Now, if i use the direction vector's x,y,z for this command, will it fire parallel to the facing direction from the character's current position? or do i have to do any extra calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I am finally able to resolve it. Actually it's pretty simple vector mathematics. The rotation matrix was already giving me the direction vector as Steve suggests above, but I had to fire along that line to some particular point to make my animation working...So I actually needed a point along the line denoted by the direction vector. So, i just calculated a point some 1000 units away from the character's current position along the direction vector and fired at the line, it worked!

```
 Vector3 facingDirection = new Vector3(RotMatrix[2, 0], RotMatrix[2, 1], RotMatrix[2, 2]); // direction vector
                    Vector3 currentPos = new Vector3(character.PosX, character.PosY, character.PosZ); // I also have position of the character
// Now calculate a point 10000 units away along the vector line 
                    var px = currentPos.X + facingDirection.X * 10000;
                    var py = currentPos.Y + facingDirection.Y * 10000;
                    var pz = currentPos.Z + facingDirection.Z * 10000;
                    return new Vector3(px, py, pz);
```